# How do I fetch a column of URLs in Google Apps Script/Javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-tag-manager, urlfetch

I have a list of client sites on which I want to continuously check to see if they installed our GTM container tags. *I can't connect the spreadsheet to our GTM because my company has a universal login that is not the same as the Google account I'm using for the spreadsheet, and I can't add my own personal tag to the containers at this time.*
I've got it working perfectly for one site at a time, changing the cell in the script, but I can't seem to get it to work when I try to let it check them all. I'd also like it to loop without running it from the script editor. It seemed like using array.map would solve both of those at once, but I just can't figure out how to use it. I'm still really new to all of this.
Here's my working code for the individual sites (url column & gtm column are Xlookups, but I could reference the actual data, if xlookups won't work):

```
function verifyGTM() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('February 2023 Paste');
  var urlRange = s.getRange(5,10);
  var gtmRange = s.getRange(5,11);
  var url = urlRange.getDisplayValues();
  var gtmID = gtmRange.getDisplayValues();
  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const mainRegex = /<!-- Google Tag Manager -->([\s\S]*?)<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->/gi;
  var results = str.match(mainRegex);
  
    Logger.log(results)
    if(str.includes("GTM") && str.includes(gtmID) && !gtmID == "N/A"){
      s.getRange(5,12).setValue("Yes");
    }
    else if(str.includes("GTM") && !str.includes(gtmID)){
      s.getRange(5,12).setValue("Incorrect GTM");
    }
    else if(gtmID == "N/A"){
      s.getRange(5,12).setValue("No GTM");
    }
    else {
      s.getRange(5,12).setValue("No");
    }
    
    

}
```

And here's an example spreadsheet with some sensitive data removed: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xgrGVbIiPJiYis3jkBsoyzAUkudOjLLKgYRMGPVsYQ/edit?usp=sharing

I've got some onEdit scripts running, but I don't think those would affect this one.

I tried using fetchAll, as seen below:

```
function verifyGTM() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('February 2023 Paste');
  var urlRange = s.getRange("J:J");
  var gtmRange = s.getRange("K:K");
  var url = urlRange.getDisplayValues();
  var gtmID = gtmRange.getDisplayValues();
  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(url).getContentText();
  const mainRegex = /<!-- Google Tag Manager -->([\s\S]*?)<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->/gi;
  var results = str.match(mainRegex);
  
    Logger.log(results)
    if(str.includes("GTM") && str.includes(gtmID) && !gtmID == "N/A"){
      s.getRange("L:L").setValue("Yes");
    }
    else if(str.includes("GTM") && !str.includes(gtmID)){
      s.getRange("L:L").setValue("Incorrect GTM");
    }
    else if(gtmID == "N/A"){
      s.getRange("L:L").setValue("No GTM");
    }
    else {
      s.getRange("L:L").setValue("No");
    }
    
    

}
```

And I received this error:
*Exception: Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.*

I tried putting utilities.sleep in, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I think that in your script, it is required to fix the way for using fetchAll. But, first, I would like to correctly understand your current situation. About `I received this error: Exception: Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.`, how do you run your script of `verifyGTM()`?

Comment: As of right now, just hitting "run" from the script editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the URLs from values from columns "J" and "K", respectively.
- You want to retrieve the values from the response values and your if statement, and want to put the values in column "L".
- From `As of right now, just hitting "run" from the script editor.`, you run your script of `verifyGTM()` by the script editor.

#### Modification points:

- As I have already mentioned in my comment, I think that it is required to fix the way for using fetchAll. The argument of `fetchAll` is required to be a 1-dimensional array including URLs or an object. But, in your script, a 2-dimensional array retrieved by `getDisplayValues()` is directly used.
- `fetchAll` returns an array of `UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse[]`. But, you directly use `getContentText()` like `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(url).getContentText();`.
- I think that `!gtmID == "N/A"` should be `gtmID != "N/A"`.
- In your situation, I thought that it might be required to check whether URL and gtmID are existing in the row.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function verifyGTM() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('February 2023 Paste');
  var range = s.getRange("J1:K" + s.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var { requests, gtmIDs, index } = values.reduce((o, [url, id], i) => {
    if (url && id) {
      o.requests.push({ url, muteHttpExceptions: true });
      o.gtmIDs.push(id);
      o.index.push(i);
    }
    return o;
  }, { requests: [], gtmIDs: [], index: [] });
  const mainRegex = /<!-- Google Tag Manager -->([\s\S]*?)<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->/gi;
  var resposes = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests).map((r, i) => {
    if (r.getResponseCode() != 200) return [null];
    var gtmID = gtmIDs[i];
    var str = r.getContentText();
    var results = str.match(mainRegex);
    Logger.log(results)
    if (str.includes("GTM") && str.includes(gtmID) && gtmID != "N/A") {
      return ["Yes"];
    } else if (str.includes("GTM") && !str.includes(gtmID)) {
      return ["Incorrect GTM"];
    } else if (gtmID == "N/A") {
      return ["No GTM"];
    }
    return ["No"];
  });
  var len = values.length;
  var res = Array(len).fill([null]);
  index.forEach((e, i) => res[e] = resposes[i]);
  range.offset(0, 2, len, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from columns "J" and "K", and the data is retrieved from all URLs of column "J", and create an output array using the values of column "K" and the retrieved data from URLs, and put the output values to column "L".

#### Note:

- When I tested this modified script using your provided Spreadsheet, the following values are put into column "L". If you change your spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

  ```
  Yes
  No GTM
  No
  Yes
  Incorrect GTM
  Yes
  Incorrect GTM
  No GTM
  Incorrect GTM
  Yes
  Yes
  Yes
  Yes
  ```
- This modified script supposes that your if statement, values of columns "J" and "K" can be used for obtaining your expected values. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Yes to everything! This is EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: @Michelle Schnitzmeier Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch a column:

```
function fetchAColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  const col1 = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //col1 is a column of values as a two dimensional array
}
```

Try this:

```
function fetchAColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const c = 1; //column number
  const sr = 2; //data start row
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  const col1 = sh.getRange(sr,c,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  //col1 is a column of values as a flattened array
}
```

If you wish to combine them with comma you can just use the join method.  If you are missing urls in some case then I would use the filter method to remove those lines.  You did not provide any details regarding the data and I don't follow links to other spreadsheets.

Comment: That didn't work for me, unfortunately. I got a bad request error listing all the URLs with commas.